# PM2 doesn't pick errors spat out by Winston in console

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, pm2, winston

I'm new to both PM2 and Winston. I have the following configuration for Winston

**logger.js**

```
'use strict'

const { createLogger, format, transports } = require('winston');
const configs = require('../app');
const ENV = configs.ENV;
const logLevel = ((ENV.toLowerCase() === 'dev') || (ENV.toLowerCase() === 'uat') ? 'debug' : 'info');

let customFormat = format(info => {
    if (info instanceof Error) {
        return Object.assign({}, info, {
            extra : info.extra,
            message: info.message,
            stack: info.stack
        });
    }
    else {
        return Object.assign({}, info, {
            message : info.message,
            data : info.data
        })
    }
})

let logger = createLogger({
    level : logLevel,
    format : format.combine(
        format.colorize(),
        format.simple(),
        format.timestamp(),
        customFormat()
    ),
    transports : [
        new transports.Console({
            handleExceptions : true,
            format : format.simple()
        })
    ],
    exitOnError : false,
})


exports.info = (message, additionalData) => {
    let logBody = {
        message : message,
        data : additionalData
    }
    logger.info(logBody);
}

exports.debug = (message, additionalData) => {
    let logBody = {
        message : message,
        data : additionalData
    }
    logger.debug(logBody);
}

exports.error = (message, error) => {
    error.extra = message;
    logger.error(error);
}
```

Then I have my PM2 config file
**app.config.json**

```
{
    "apps" : [
        {
            "name" : "app",
            "script" : "./src/app.js",
            "instances" : "1",
            "exec_mode" : "cluster"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now, when I run the app with the command `pm2 start app.config.json` and check the error log at `~/.pm2/logs/app-error-0.log`, I see only warnings getting logged.

The app crashes and restarts several times because it has a dependency on MongoDB and if MongoDB is not running, the app must not start.

However, I don't see the error logs anywhere printed on error file.

But when I run the same app with command `node ./src/app.js`, I see the following error logs printed on the console

```
error: failed to connect to server [127.0.0.1:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017] {"name":"MongoNetworkError",
"errorLabels":["TransientTransactionError"],
"extra":"Error connecting to APP DB: ",
"timestamp":"2019-01-21T12:18:15.354Z","stack":"MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [127.0.0.1:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]\n    at Pool.<anonymous> (/home/Auro/sampleProject/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:564:11)\n................"}
```

The snippet of code where I am logging the error:

```
const logger = require('../../logger')
........
........
dbConnection.on('error', (err) => {
    logger.error('Error connecting to APP DB: ', err);
    process.exit(1);
})
```

Where am I going wrong? Why isn't PM2 picking the winston error printed on console? I know PM2 works with `console.log` very well, but how do I get it to work with winston?

Comment: comment this line `const logLevel = ((ENV.toLowerCase() === 'dev') || (ENV.toLowerCase() === 'uat') ? 'debug' : 'info'); ` and make `const logLevel='error'` and see if it catches `error`